# Install mailx on CentOS 9

Tags: centos, mailx

I can't install `mailx` on CentOS 9.

```
 yum install mailx -y


Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:13 ago on Sat 09 Apr 2022 07:55:59 PM UTC.
No match for argument: mailx
Error: Unable to find a match: mailx
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [Bugzilla Bug 2001537 "mailx -> s-nail replacement in CentOS Stream 9"](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2001537), `mailx` was replaced by `s-nail`. There's also a reference to the same in the [Red Hat's "Considerations in adopting RHEL 9" - Appendix A. Change to packages - Package replacements](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_9/assembly_changes-to-packages_considerations-in-adopting-rhel-9).

Install the replacement package with: `yum install s-nail`.

Comment: I also had to do `yum install sendmail && systemctl start sendmail` to be able to send email using `mailx` command.